# Download all Play Store metadata using fastlane supply excluding screenshots

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane, fastlane-supply

I'd like to download all of the latest metadata from the Play Store using `fastlane supply`.

This seems possible using:

```
fastlane supply init
```

but this will download all screenshots also. I'd like to just get the text.

Bonus points: can it overwrite the existing `metadata` directory? It throws an error if the directory exists.